# Using GLKView with a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, glkit

I wanted to use OpenGL to do some simple Image processing, so I started off with `GLKView`. Since I don't need to refresh the view every few seconds, I didn't use the `GLKViewController` and instead used a normal `UIViewController` subclass.

My question is that do I simply make the viewController's view as a `GLKView` or do I add the `GLKView` as a subview of the view controller's view. Since I'm adding a `UISlider` to the view as  well, I think the latter seems better, but I'm not sure. I also need to call `setNeedsDisplay` on the GLKView on certain occasions.

Comment: Before you get too far into rolling your own OpenGL ES image processing solution, you might want to take a look at this: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Comment: Hey Brad, I've already checked out all your work and it has certainly helped me a lot (the lecture, your code, big fan!), but I wanted to do things from scratch to learn as much as  could, which is why I started with GLKViews.

Comment: I just wrote that because people were having real troubles around setting up the scaffolding required to do shader-based image processing. Haven't worked much with GLKit myself (have been maintaining 4.0 support in things), but if a GLKView behaves like a standard CAEAGLLayer-backed UIView it should support subviews. That would let you use it either as the primary view for a view controller or a subview of that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your rendering, you should really be using GLKView inside a GLKViewController. if you're worried about not needing to refresh all the time, use self.paused = YES inside your GLKViewController, this will stop the rendering loop, and when you need to render again, simply do self.paused = NO.

if you're having the glkview inside another view, you should set it up with containment. in your case, you should have a normal UIView with a normal UIViewController, then add the UISlider and your GLKViewController (with the GLKView) to that.

After this is done, you can do your normal view stuff in your parent controller, and your opengl stuff is your glk controller.

A simple example to do this, having setup your parent, which contains the UISlider:

inside the custom UIViewController for the parent

```
@interface ParentViewController () {
    ...
    UISlider *_slider; // this is your slider
    CustomGLKViewController *_myGlkViewController;
}
```

then inside viewDidLoad:

```
// assuming you're using a storyboard
UIStoryboard *myStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                                      bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];


// setup the opengl controller
// first get an instance from storyboard
_myGlkViewController = [myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"idForGlkViewController"];
// then add the glkview as the subview of the parent view
[self.view addSubview:_myGlkViewController.view];
// add the glkViewController as the child of self
[self addChildViewController:_myGlkViewController];
[_myGlkViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

// if you want to set the glkView to the same size as the parent view, 
// or you can do stuff like this inside myGlkViewController
_myGlkViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
```

but this is just a simple example to help you get started, you should really go read the apple docs on UIViewController containment for ios5 and the docs for GLKit