# how to increase the size of the cube-openGL

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, cube, glkview

I am trying to display cube and rotating it.I have succeded in doing this [glkview drawinrect delegate method called only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962882/glkview-drawinrect-delegate-method-called-only-once)

I have taken the code to set up the cube from here http://www.raywenderlich.com/5235/beginning-opengl-es-2-0-with-glkit-part-2 which I mentioned in the above referenced link.

Now my problem is I want to increase the size of my cube.

Here is the code which makes my code to rotate.

```
#pragma mark - GLKViewControllerDelegate

- (void)update {

    float aspect = fabsf(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height);
    GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(65.0f), aspect, 4.0f, 10.0f);    
    self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;

    GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -6.0f);
    _rotation += -90 * self.timeSinceLastUpdate;//90 clockwise -90 anticlickwise
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(0), 1, 0, 0);
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, GLKMathDegreesToRadians(_rotation), 0, 1, 0);

    self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = modelViewMatrix;

}
```

Can someone guide me how to increase my cube?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you've posted isn't even the code that sets up the cube.

Comment: I have taken the code to set up the cube from here http://www.raywenderlich.com/5235/beginning-opengl-es-2-0-with-glkit-part-2 which I mensioned in the above referenced link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16962882/glkview-drawinrect-delegate-method-called-only-once

Comment: So what have you tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing experiments,in decreasing GLKMathDegreesToRadians value to lesser values increasing my cube size.problem solved.

```
GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(35.0f), aspect, 4.0f, 10.0f);
```